# Why does my program take user input before prompting the user?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a console program that asks the user for their name, and greets them. I am coding in Notepad++, and running it in the git bash console. My code is:

```
puts "Hello, please type in your name: "
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello #{name}, it is a pleasure to meet you!"
```

When it runs, it waits for user input, and once that is entered, it prints:

```
Hello, please type in your name:
Hello <name_the_user_entered>, it is a pleasure to meet you!
```

Even though the user prompt is first in the code, it accepts user input before any test is printed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Are you running with `ruby your_filename.rb`?

Comment: Hi @ggorlen thanks for taking a look at it. I am typing it that way into the console, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby might be buffering output. To force it, use `flush`:

```
$stdout.puts "Hello, please type in your name: "
$stdout.flush
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello #{name}, it is a pleasure to meet you!"
```

But I think in newer Ruby versions, this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This did it, thank you @mb21. Just a note, it required a $ before stdout in order to compile correctly.

Comment: @moldymold ruby is not compiled by any mean and no, it **does not** require `$` in front of `STDOUT`. Make sure you typed it in uppercase, ruby is case sensitive.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I apologize, I am new to Ruby so I did not realize it is not compiled. At the time of my previous comment, the `STDOUT` was `stdout`, in which case it would need to be `$stdout`. I appreciate you taking the time to clarify!

Comment: Usually it's a good practice to use `$stdout, $stdin, $stderr` instead of `STDOUT, STDIN,STDERR`. The upper case versions are constants and always point to the real streams, users or tests may want to override those to for example capture and validate command output, which you can do by using the `$` versions.